# Flutter, Flare: Execute function on end of animation

Tags: flutter, flare

I have a simple question but can't find an answer to it: Is there a way to execute a function after my Flare animation is finished? I have an animation that is shown on the app launch and I want the home screen to be shown after the animation is over. How can I do this?
I tried using Future.delayed() but don't know where to put the function. If I put it into the builder of the StartAnimation widget, the EnterExitRoute is executed over and over again.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'animations.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';

String _animationName = "Start";

Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                EnterExitRoute(exitPage: this, enterPage: HomeScreen()));
          },
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: 875,
                  child: FlareActor(
                    'src/animation.flr',
                    animation: _animationName,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The final code, working:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'animations.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';

String _animationName = "Start";
bool _appStart = true;

[in build method]
  if (_appStart == true) {
              Navigator.push(context,
                EnterExitRoute(exitPage: this, enterPage: HomeScreen()));
              _appStart = false;
            }
[end of build method]

Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 875,
                child: FlareActor(
                  'src/animation.flr',
                  animation: _animationName,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: where is the callback ?

Answer (score 2):

The `FlareActor` widget has a [callback](https://pub.dev/documentation/flare_flutter/latest/flare_actor/FlareActor/callback.html) parameter for that:

```dart
/// Callback invoked when [animation] has completed. If [animation] is looping
/// this callback is never invoked.
final FlareCompletedCallback callback;
```

Other alternative is to use a `FlareControls` that has a [method](https://pub.dev/documentation/flare_flutter/latest/flare_controls/FlareControls/onCompleted.html) `onCompleted(String name)`:

```dart
/// Listen for when the animation called [name] has completed.
void onCompleted(String name) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the callback

```
child: FlareActor(
    'src/animation.flr',
    animation: _animationName,
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    callback: (animationName) {
        // Your code here. This is executed when the animation ends.
        // If the animation is looping, then it will never be called.
    },
),
```